# Configuring VLANs on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, vlan

I've tried to configure 2 VLANs on one physical interface `ens33`. And `ens34` is used to access the internet But I can't ping VM from other hosts. The VM network adapter is in 192.168.100.0/22 network.

The `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`:

```
  ethernets:
    ens33:
      dhcp4: true
    ens34:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2
  vlans:
    ens33.100:
      id: 100
      link: ens33
      addresses:
      - 192.168.100.70/24
    ens33.101:
      id: 101
      link: ens33
      addresses:
      - 192.168.101.70/24
```

The `ip addr`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:86:1c:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s1
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe86:1c1d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ens34: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:86:1c:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp2s2
    inet 192.168.0.5/24 metric 100 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic ens34
       valid_lft 86371sec preferred_lft 86371sec
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe86:1c27/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: ens33.100@ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:86:1c:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.100.70/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global ens33.100
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe86:1c1d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: ens33.101@ens33: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:0c:29:86:1c:1d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.101.70/24 brd 192.168.101.255 scope global ens33.101
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe86:1c1d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The 802.1q is supported:

```
root@gateway:~# lsmod | grep 8021q
8021q                  36864  0
garp                   20480  1 8021q
mrp                    20480  1 8021q
```

And traffic between two VMs is untagged, host 192.168.100.70 don't reply on ARP messages. [Traffic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxCva.png)

Could you help me to find out the problem, please?